# Wordpress hyperlink parameter redirect to wrong page on Nginx

Tags: wordpress, nginx, hyperlink

i have wordpress installed on Nginx webserver 
and when i make a hyperlink on it, 
example :

https://hyperlink.com/cart.php?a=add&pid=89

but when i click the link from the site

it will become

https://hyperlink.com/?a=add&pid=89

anyone ever face this problem? Thank You.

Comment: you need to change your permalink. refer this URL:  https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks

Comment: @WillyRL - you check the website permalink. after you try to access the pages.

Comment: i think permalink just for the pages, and posts, doesn't affect any hyperlink on pages, am i right?